# Conditionally execute the switchMap, otherwise, cancel all without firing the error event

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm doing a web application in Angular 10. I try to keep working with Observables instead of Promises, but sometimes is hard to build a flow of executions.

I want to accomplish this flow:

1. Present a confirmation modal
2. If the confirmation has a value (`{isConfirmed: true}`), present a loading (here is the condition).
3. Do a `switchMap` to start the execution of HTTP calls.
4. If any HTTP call fails, hide the loading and show a warning message

Logic:

```
  send(title: string, message): Observable<any> {
    const isConfirmed: Promise<{isConfirmed: boolean}> = this.alertService.warningConfirmation(
      'Send message',
      'Are you sure you want to send the message?',
      'Send',
      'Cancel'
    );

    return from(isConfirmed)
      .pipe(
        tap(res => res.isConfirmed ? this.loadingService.present() : EMPTY),
        switchMap(res => from(this.service.httpCallOneGetUsers())
          .pipe(
            map(users => users.map(user => user.email)),
            switchMap(emails => this.service.httpCallTwoSendMessage(title, message, emails))
          )
        ),
        finalize(() => this.loadingService.dismiss()),
        tap({
          next: () => console.log('Message sent!'),
          error: () => console.log('Could not send the message.')
        })
      );
  }
```

When I cancel the confirmation, the error event is fired. Also, the loading is never shown.

I have 2 HTTP calls inside the first `switchMap` and both may fail, one returns a Promise and the other returns an Observable. That's why I have added the first HTTP call inside of `from()`.

My goal is:

1. Conditionally execute/enter the `switchMap` if the confirmation result is `isConfirmed: true`. Otherwise, cancel all and get out of the logic without firing the error event.
2. Where is the perfect location to add the `tap` or `finalize` to hide the loading and show a success/error message to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1

> Conditionally execute/enter the `switchMap` if the confirmation result is `isConfirmed: true`.

Try [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter). E.g:

```js
from(isConfirmed).pipe(
  filter((res) => !!res.isConfirmed)
  ...
)
```

This will only emit values that match the filter condition.

### 2

> Where is the perfect location to add the tap or finalize...?

- `finalize`: At the end, so if any subscription fails before it, it is executed.
- `tap`: Wherever you want something to be executed. For example, if you wanted to print users o emails you'd need to put the `tap` instruction in the part of the pipe where you have that data.

---

Summarizing:

```js
from(isConfirmed).pipe(
  filter((res) => !!res.isConfirmed),
  switchMap((res) => from(this.service.httpCallOneGetUsers())),
  map((users) => users.map((user) => user.email)),
  switchMap((emails) =>
    this.service.httpCallTwoSendMessage(title, message, emails)
  ),
  finalize(() => this.loadingService.dismiss()),
  tap({
    next: () => console.log("Message sent!"),
    error: () => console.log("Could not send the message."),
  })
);
```

Note: the last `tap` acts like the receiver of the subscription result, thats why it is last. But that code should go in the `subscribe`.

### UPDATE (from comments)

To finalize the observable when the condition is not met you should do something like this:

```js
from(isConfirmed).pipe(
  switchMap((res) => {
    if (res.isConfirmed) {
      this.loadingService.present();
      return from(this.service.httpCallOneGetUsers());
    } else {
      throwError("");
    }
  }),
  map((users) => users.map((user) => user.email)),
  switchMap((emails) =>
    this.service.httpCallTwoSendMessage(title, message, emails)
  ),
  finalize(() => this.loadingService.dismiss()),
  tap({
    next: () => console.log("Message sent!"),
    error: () => console.log("Could not send the message."),
  })
);
```

If the condition is true, the pipe will execute in order as expected. If the condition is false, from the first `switchMap` it will jump to `finalize`.

Comment: Where to add the code of presenting the loading? Maybe after the `filter` using another `switchMap` ? Also, I don't understand the `filter`, you are saying that if its value is `true` the flow will continue, if it's `false` then, the `tap` or `finalize` will be called?

Comment: Yes. Presenting the loading has nothing to do with the pipe, so use `tap` (which is like an external execution that does not modify the result of the pipe).

If the filter matches, the flow continues; if not, it does not emit a value (so `finalize` and tap are not called)

Comment: @RRGT19 I've updated my answer with that scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it like the following:

```
return from(isConfirmed)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(res => res.isConfirmed ? of(res) : EMPTY),
        tap(() => this.loadingService.present()),
        switchMap(res => from(this.service.httpCallOneGetUsers()).pipe(...)
        ...
```

The only change is that I'm, using `switchMap` and `tap()` at the beginning. If `res.isConfirmed === false` then you retuirn `EMPTY` that will not trigger any of the following operators (it's just a `complete` notification). When it's `true` then I'm returning the original `res` object with `of(res)`.

To hide the loading the best operator is most likely `finalize()` because it's triggered when the chain is being disposed which is after it completes, errors or it's unsubscribed.

Comment: My console logs inside of the `tap` operator are not executing. Maybe there is a weird behavior when using `finalize` and `tap` one after the other? I have tried deleting the `finalize` operator and dismiss the loading inside of the `tap` events with the help of `async/await`. I hate duplicating the code to dismiss the modal but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: `tap` and `finalize` can both work in the same chain so the problem will be somewhere else. `tap` also doesn't wait for Proimse resolution with await. I can't give you any better advice without a reproducible demo.